# MS Graph API - How to bring more than 100 lists from contracts endpoint?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/contract-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

[image]

[image]

I got a contract list through the contract endpoint, but I could only get up to 100 lists, and I couldn't get a list that exceeded them.

Is there any data that needs to be added when requesting api To bring more than 101 lists?
(Currently, our company has more than 150 contracts.)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add `$top` query parameter to specify the page size of the result set.

The minimum value of `$top` is 1 and the maximum depends on the corresponding API.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contracts?$top=500
```

Otherwise, you will need to use `@odata.nextLink` property to get next 100 results.

Resources:

[Top parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter)

[Paging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging)